# Where can I find the full contents of the iOS root (/) directory?

Tags: c#, ios, exploit

I am an exploit developer/penetration tester for Maroon Penetration Testing based in Oklahoma (private organization) and I am currently looking for vulnerabilities in iOS, but I would either need the source code of iOS or the system files (root or / directory). I am running iOS 10.2.1 and it is nearly impossible to jailbreak the device, downgrading is not an option either. If there is anywhere I can download the source of iOS 10.2.1/ the root directory contents that would be awesome, or if there is any way to retrieve them myself that would be even better.

Regards,
 Noodles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any kind of source code for IOS version 10.2.1, and I don't think it's possible, but the closest I've found is

https://opensource.apple.com/release/ios-1021.html

Good luck with your exploitatious endeavors!

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's still source code :)